# What is the difference between owns and owns(effective) in cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I am trying to check status of nodes using nodetool
When i try **nodetool status** i get the following output

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.12  702.25 MB  256     23.5%  3ef5a6e7-123b-48cd-b486-8b6f61121a0c  RAC2
UN  192.168.1.31  884.69 MB  256     25.6%  ff0f1746-0379-4928-84b0-11efabbeea13  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.8   2.84 MB    1       0.1%   5fb9e1fa-c181-43a9-ac77-5578a1ee2086  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.27  692.18 MB  256     24.1%  95659096-97ef-419f-bd82-693f19ad7679  RAC2
UN  192.168.1.32  1.02 GB    256     26.7%  25a0c51a-9ffd-40f2-9e20-6899f36e8f3c  RAC1
```

But When i check status for a particular keyspace e.g **nodetool status keyspacetest**

```
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.12  702.16 MB  256     49.2%             3ef5a6e7-123b-48cd-b486-8b6f61121a0c  RAC2
UN  192.168.1.31  884.69 MB  256     48.0%             ff0f1746-0379-4928-84b0-11efabbeea13  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.8   2.84 MB    1       0.1%              5fb9e1fa-c181-43a9-ac77-5578a1ee2086  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.27  692.18 MB  256     50.8%             95659096-97ef-419f-bd82-693f19ad7679  RAC2
UN  192.168.1.32  1.02 GB    256     51.9%             25a0c51a-9ffd-40f2-9e20-6899f36e8f3c  RAC1
```

Now from the Owns % i understand how much % of data each nodes has and sum of all that give me 100% But for Owns(Effective) the % values is very different and  the sum is around 200%.

I am confused with this stats.Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Owns (effective)** shows numbers where replication factor is taken into account.

Thus in case of *nodetool status keyspacetest* it shows how much data with replicas each node is holding.

In other words, in your cluster you have 5 nodes (with unevenly spreaded vnodes). 4 out of 5 nodes has effectively ~50% of existing data in that keyspace.